# -verbose garbage collector interpretation

Tags: jboss, garbage-collection

I'm running jboss 5.1 and I get this GC data

```
34.098: [GC 197635K->91639K(236480K), 0.0356348 secs]
37.139: [GC 217911K->100951K(239936K), 0.0541968 secs]
37.194: [Full GC 100951K->97239K(304704K), 0.3325776 secs]
38.602: [GC 214271K->97547K(285568K), 0.0488937 secs]
41.395: [GC 220811K->111699K(304512K), 0.0334592 secs]
42.734: [GC 235155K->115815K(304384K), 0.0208743 secs]
43.722: [GC 239271K->115801K(303872K), 0.0166861 secs]
44.373: [GC 241049K->118266K(304128K), 0.0106151 secs
```

can somebody explain when Full GC occurs why there is such small difference between before and after heap size shouldn't it be bigger when full GC. line before full GC is "normal" GC and it has this large difference (and small collection time?), I only noticed that timestamps for this two lines are very close

Answer (score 0):

What you see is both, collections happening in young/eden space and in old space. Those two spaces use different kind of collectors because the objects in those areas have different characteristics.
Those Full GCs are usually the biggest problem, because they are slow and they halt your VM. You luckily do not have a big issue yet, but your question is why it was caused.

Unfortunately it is impossible to say.
If you want to know more, you should activate the switch `-XX:+PrintGCDetails`

However, we can guess. As you correctly point out, the heap was not full (100MB out of 300MB) and it does not collect much (30MB).
So I am guessing that this GC was caused by a call to `System.GC()`. You should use -`XX:+DisableExplicitGC` to prevent them from happening, or you find the code that has actually done this and remove it.

Comment: I'm just wondering, maybe it is normal to have those Full GC  on app server startup? Because after server is up, I have no full collections from there on.